2fa Application time cannot be synchronized with the server
My github uses 2fa,Can't log in now.I have a password and username and use 2fa---Authy,And it works fine, but I can't log into my github account. After entering the 2fa code it prompts:Two-factor authentication failed.
A lot of searching possibilities showed that maybe the problem was with the timing, my phone number in the app was from the UK and is now in China. 2fa Application time cannot be synchronized with the server，How to solve this problem？

Contact support.

Please, contact the support and submit a ticket.
https://authy.com/help/

Contacted but it didn't help, I've now changed my phone number to China, however I still can't log in to github and it even prompts the token issue sometimes
